# Void method printing two times

Tags: java

Hello I am trying to understand the code I have written and why does it print the output below

```
public void isSymmetricNow(int[][] matrix){
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] != matrix[j][i]) {
                System.out.print("matrix is not symmetric \n");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("matrix is symmetric \n");
}
```

prints me

```
matrix is not symmetric 
matrix is not symmetric 
matrix is symmetric
```

ASSUME THAT the given matrix is not symmetric here.

```
int matrix3[][] = {{1,4,7},{-4,6,6},{7,6,9}};
```

How can I modify this code to give me back saying if the matrix is symmetric or not only once.

Comment: break it using `break outer`

Comment: @UmaKanth While your answer may be correct, please answer the question in the answer section rather  than comments

Comment: you can set a flag value and then check that value to print the desired result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a plain return statement will do. It will not execute again if the condition is false.

```
public void isSymmetricNow(int[][] matrix){
    //Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            //matrix[i][j] = random.nextInt(20);
            if (matrix[i][j] != matrix[j][i]) {
                System.out.print("matrix is not symmetric \n");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("matrix is symmetric \n");
}
```

Or

You could return a boolean saying it is a Symmetric or not.

```
public boolean isSymmetricNow(int[][] matrix){
    //Random random = new Random();
     for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            //matrix[i][j] = random.nextInt(20);
            if (matrix[i][j] != matrix[j][i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

then call it using your function.

```
if(isSymmetric(matrix))
    System.out.println("Symmetric");
else
    System.out.println("Not Symmetric");
```

Comment: Yes, If the condition isn't satisfied it comes out of the outer loop. Maybe you want to return a `boolean` as Eran suggested.

Comment: I have a boolean method and that works as expected but I was just curious to see what happens with void. Another question, when I break outer it still prints the last line of matrix being symmetric. Is there a way in `void` to return just the specific output? in this case being not symmetric

Comment: Because it is outside the loops and always called. adding a return statement would do.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your loops will print "matrix is not symmetric \n" whenever they find `i` and `j` for which `matrix[i][j] != matrix[j][i]`, which can happen more than once.

and `System.out.print("matrix is symmetric \n");` is always called, so that explains the last line of output.

You probably want your method to have a boolean return value instead of printing this output. This way the loops will only iterate until you find out that the matrix is not symmetric.

```
public boolean isSymmetricNow(int[][] matrix){
    //Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            //matrix[i][j] = random.nextInt(20);
            if (matrix[i][j] != matrix[j][i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

To do the same without a return value :

```
public void isSymmetricNow(int[][] matrix){
    //Random random = new Random();
    boolean isSymmetric = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length && isSymmetric; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length && isSymmetric; j++) {
            //matrix[i][j] = random.nextInt(20);
            if (matrix[i][j] != matrix[j][i]) {
                System.out.print("matrix is not symmetric \n");
                isSymmetric = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (isSymmetric)
        System.out.print("matrix is symmetric \n");
}
```

Comment: I have a boolean method but I am learning java and trying to make this method specifically with void.

Comment: Then add a check using a boolean variable

Comment: @Mani In that case, you should break out of the loops once you find the matrix is not symmetric, and only print the last line of output if you didn't break out of the loops. You'll need some boolean variable for that.

Answer (score 0):

1) As Eran pointed out, i and j aren't equal more than once and hence will keep printing for as long as the loop iterates. I suggest using a break statement to exit out of the loop the very first time it finds that i != j.

2)The last print statement will be called irrespective of how the the loop behaves and whether the matrix is symmetric or not. I suggest printing that the matrix is symmetric by creating another if statement outside the loop to check symmetry.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void isSymmetricNow(int[][] matrix){
    //Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            //matrix[i][j] = random.nextInt(20);
            if (matrix[i][j] != matrix[j][i]) {
                System.out.print("matrix is not symmetric \n");
                return; //When it does not symetric, return.
            }
        }
   }
   System.out.print("matrix is symmetric \n");
}
```